# iCloud documents "waiting"

Tags: macos, icloud, data-synchronization

Ever since I restored my Mac from a Time Machine backup to return from Yosemite to Mavericks, things have been a mess. I fixed everything but iCloud sync, which seems to be an impossible issue. It simply refuses to sync. The files are always "Waiting", no matter what I do. I've deleted the `Ubiquity` folder, replaced the `Mobile Documents` folder, run `killall -9 ubd`, rebooted about 20 times, and so on. Any other ideas out there?

Answer (score 2):

Upgrading to iCloud Drive is a one-time, **irreversible action**. You can not go back from iCloud Drive to Documents & Data—your Apple ID has been permanently upgraded.

> Migrating to iCloud Drive will disable Documents & Data syncing for your iCloud account on OS X Mavericks and earlier Macs, as well as iOS 7 and earlier devices.

<sup>Source: OS X Yosemite release notes</sup>